# Returning Error code and event from SQL Server procedure call

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to setup a Powershell script to run some SQL Server stored procedures. Initially, the script returned just either a zero or non-zero return code (by evaluating the catch block), depending on whether the procedure call failed or not:

```
try {
        $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.sqlCommand ("$query", $connection)          
        $DataAdapter = new-object System.data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
        $dataset = new-object System.data.Dataset

        $rowCount = $DataAdapter.Fill($dataset)
        if($rowCount -gt 0) {
            $DataAdapter.Fill($dataset) | Out-Null
            $return =,[int]$command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value
            $return += ,$dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]
        } else{
            $return=,[int]$command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value             
        }
    }
    catch {
        $return=,10000
        throw
    }
```

Now I want to make it a bit more usable and return the error message if the job fails.  To do this, I am using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler`, which seems to work, except it doesn't fall into the catch block and therefore doesn't evaluate the other return code.  This is the code (the full function):

```
function Run-SQLQuery($dataSource, $database, $query) {
$stuffedMessage = ""
$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {param($sender, $error) $stuffedMessage +=  "$($_)" };    
try {       
    try {
        $connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource; " +
            "Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
            "Initial Catalog=$database"

        # Create a connection to the OLAP Database
        $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)         
        $connection.add_InfoMessage($handler); 
        $connection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true;
        $connection.Open()
    }
    catch {
        $return = ,"unable to open connection"
        throw
    }

    try {
        $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.sqlCommand ("$query", $connection)

        $DataAdapter = new-object System.data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
        $dataset = new-object System.data.Dataset

        $rowCount = $DataAdapter.Fill($dataset)
        $return = ,$stuffedMessage
        $return +=[int]$command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value
        if($rowCount -gt 0) {

            $DataAdapter.Fill($dataset) | Out-Null
            $return +=[int]$command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value
            $return +=$dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]
        } else{
            $return +=[int]$command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value                
        }
    }
    catch {
        $return=,10000
        throw
    }       
    $connection.close()
}
catch {
}
Finally
{
    $connection.dispose()
    ,$return
}
```

I don't want to evaluate the return message to determine whether the proc has errored out. Can anyone recommend a method or way to both capture the message as well as a full proof way to show that the proc call has either been successful or a failure?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe you could add `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` to the `Try` clause. See if this helps to get in the `Catch` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DarkLite1.  I gave that a try and no joy.  I've also tried setting `FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors` to `$false` and returning `$stuffedMessage` in the `catch` block, but this brings back null.

I could do a comparison on the string in `$stuffedMessage`, but I am mindful that these values could be different and not as consistent as I would like.

Comment: Instead of creating your own function to trigger a stored procedure you could try to use `Invoke-Sqlcmd2`. There's a question [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7985b7ef-ed89-4dfd-b02a-433cc4e30894/view/Discussions) on how to launch a stored procedure. The latest version can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1). Maybe this can help you out.

Comment: OK, I am not sure whether this is what I need for the purpose.  I don't want the script to fail if there is a SQL issue - I want it to return the SQL return message, so it can be used downstream.  Using -Verbose lets the script continue, but I am not sure whether this is wise in a automated production environment.  I'm new to powershell (most of my other scripts have been done in Perl), so I am still trying to understand what is acceptable practice or not.

Comment: @DarkLite1 - Thanks for your help.  The more I dig into it, the more I have determined that Invoke-Sqlcmd2 will do what I want, with a few modifications.  I have modified it to return the error message in an array if it fails on the connections or the queries.  I still have to do a switch and evaluate the return codes, but at least I know if there is a failure.  Cheers

Comment: That's great news! Good you found a decent workaround. It might just be a good idea to share your changes with the author of the function. So others can enjoy your improvements to.